# ThreeJS how to change text particles color

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, webgl

I have been trying for days to modify the colors in [this project](https://codepen.io/sanprieto/pen/XWNjBdb) and I couldn't

In particulat I'd like to change:

- the background color [edit, I was able to do this]
- the yellow and white fixed colors for the text in the linked snippet

I tried to do it via the `const particle = new THREE.TextureLoader(manager).load` linking to another png image but the text disappears even if the link is valid

If there is a working project similar to this please feel free to share it

Thanks!

---

```js
const preload = () => {

  let manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
  manager.onLoad = function() {
    const environment = new Environment( typo, particle );
  }

  var typo = null;
  const loader = new THREE.FontLoader( manager );
  const font = loader.load('https://res.cloudinary.com/dydre7amr/raw/upload/v1612950355/font_zsd4dr.json', function ( font ) { typo = font; });
  const particle = new THREE.TextureLoader( manager ).load( 'https://res.cloudinary.com/dfvtkoboz/image/upload/v1605013866/particle_a64uzf.png');

}

if ( document.readyState === "complete" || (document.readyState !== "loading" && !document.documentElement.doScroll))
  preload ();
else
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", preload );

class Environment {

  constructor( font, particle ){

    this.font = font;
    this.particle = particle;
    this.container = document.querySelector( '#wn-magic' );
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.createCamera();
    this.createRenderer();
    this.setup()
    this.bindEvents();
  }

  bindEvents(){

    window.addEventListener( 'resize', this.onWindowResize.bind( this ));

  }

  setup(){

    this.createParticles = new CreateParticles( this.scene, this.font,             this.particle, this.camera, this.renderer );
  }

  render() {

     this.createParticles.render()
     this.renderer.render( this.scene, this.camera )
  }

  createCamera() {

    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 65, this.container.clientWidth /  this.container.clientHeight, 1, 10000 );
    this.camera.position.set( 0,0, 100 );

  }

  createRenderer() {

    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    this.renderer.setSize( this.container.clientWidth, this.container.clientHeight );

    this.renderer.setPixelRatio( Math.min( window.devicePixelRatio, 2));

    this.renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
    this.container.appendChild( this.renderer.domElement );

    this.renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => { this.render() })

  }

  onWindowResize(){

    this.camera.aspect = this.container.clientWidth / this.container.clientHeight;
    this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    this.renderer.setSize( this.container.clientWidth, this.container.clientHeight );

  }
}

class CreateParticles {

    constructor( scene, font, particleImg, camera, renderer ) {

        this.scene = scene;
        this.font = font;
        this.particleImg = particleImg;
        this.camera = camera;
        this.renderer = renderer;

        this.raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
        this.mouse = new THREE.Vector2(-200, 200);

        this.colorChange = new THREE.Color();

        this.buttom = false;

        this.data = {

            text: 'Welcome\n To Rostami\n Creative\n Studio',
            amount: 800,
            particleSize: 2,
            particleColor: 0xeeeeee,
            textSize: 16,
            area: 250,
            ease: .05,
        }

        this.setup();
        this.bindEvents();

    }


    setup(){

        const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( this.visibleWidthAtZDepth( 100, this.camera ), this.visibleHeightAtZDepth( 100, this.camera ));
        const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00, transparent: true } );
        this.planeArea = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        this.planeArea.visible = false;
        this.createText();

    }

    bindEvents() {

        document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', this.onMouseDown.bind( this ));
        document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', this.onMouseMove.bind( this ));
        document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', this.onMouseUp.bind( this ));

    }

    onMouseDown(){

        this.mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
        this.mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

        const vector = new THREE.Vector3( this.mouse.x, this.mouse.y, 0.5);
        vector.unproject( this.camera );
        const dir = vector.sub( this.camera.position ).normalize();
        const distance = - this.camera.position.z / dir.z;
        this.currenPosition = this.camera.position.clone().add( dir.multiplyScalar( distance ) );

        const pos = this.particles.geometry.attributes.position;
        this.buttom = true;
        this.data.ease = .01;

    }

    onMouseUp(){

        this.buttom = false;
        this.data.ease = .05;
    }

    onMouseMove( ) {

        this.mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
        this.mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

    }

    render( level ){

        const time = ((.001 * performance.now())%12)/12;
        const zigzagTime = (1 + (Math.sin( time * 2 * Math.PI )))/6;

        this.raycaster.setFromCamera( this.mouse, this.camera );

        const intersects = this.raycaster.intersectObject( this.planeArea );

        if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

            const pos = this.particles.geometry.attributes.position;
            const copy = this.geometryCopy.attributes.position;
            const coulors = this.particles.geometry.attributes.customColor;
            const size = this.particles.geometry.attributes.size;

            const mx = intersects[ 0 ].point.x;
            const my = intersects[ 0 ].point.y;
            const mz = intersects[ 0 ].point.z;

            for ( var i = 0, l = pos.count; i < l; i++) {

                const initX = copy.getX(i);
                const initY = copy.getY(i);
                const initZ = copy.getZ(i);

                let px = pos.getX(i);
                let py = pos.getY(i);
                let pz = pos.getZ(i);

                this.colorChange.setHSL( .5, 1 , 1 )
                coulors.setXYZ( i, this.colorChange.r, this.colorChange.g, this.colorChange.b )
                coulors.needsUpdate = true;

                size.array[ i ]  = this.data.particleSize;
                size.needsUpdate = true;

                let dx = mx - px;
                let dy = my - py;
                const dz = mz - pz;

                const mouseDistance = this.distance( mx, my, px, py )
                let d = ( dx = mx - px ) * dx + ( dy = my - py ) * dy;
                const f = - this.data.area/d;

                if( this.buttom ){

                    const t = Math.atan2( dy, dx );
                    px -= f * Math.cos( t );
                    py -= f * Math.sin( t );

                    this.colorChange.setHSL( .5 + zigzagTime, 1.0 , .5 )
                    coulors.setXYZ( i, this.colorChange.r, this.colorChange.g, this.colorChange.b )
                    coulors.needsUpdate = true;

                    if ((px > (initX + 70)) || ( px < (initX - 70)) || (py > (initY + 70) || ( py < (initY - 70)))){

                        this.colorChange.setHSL( .15, 1.0 , .5 )
                        coulors.setXYZ( i, this.colorChange.r, this.colorChange.g, this.colorChange.b )
                        coulors.needsUpdate = true;

                    }

                }else{

                    if( mouseDistance < this.data.area ){

                        if(i%5==0){

                            const t = Math.atan2( dy, dx );
                            px -= .03 * Math.cos( t );
                            py -= .03 * Math.sin( t );

                            this.colorChange.setHSL( .15 , 1.0 , .5 )
                            coulors.setXYZ( i, this.colorChange.r, this.colorChange.g, this.colorChange.b )
                            coulors.needsUpdate = true;

                            size.array[ i ]  =  this.data.particleSize /1.2;
                            size.needsUpdate = true;

                        }else{

                            const t = Math.atan2( dy, dx );
                            px += f * Math.cos( t );
                            py += f * Math.sin( t );

                            pos.setXYZ( i, px, py, pz );
                            pos.needsUpdate = true;

                            size.array[ i ]  = this.data.particleSize * 1.3 ;
                            size.needsUpdate = true;
                        }

                        if ((px > (initX + 10)) || ( px < (initX - 10)) || (py > (initY + 10) || ( py < (initY - 10)))){

                            this.colorChange.setHSL( .15, 1.0 , .5 )
                            coulors.setXYZ( i, this.colorChange.r, this.colorChange.g, this.colorChange.b )
                            coulors.needsUpdate = true;

                            size.array[ i ]  = this.data.particleSize /1.8;
                            size.needsUpdate = true;

                        }
                    }

                }

                px += ( initX  - px ) * this.data.ease;
                py += ( initY  - py ) * this.data.ease;
                pz += ( initZ  - pz ) * this.data.ease;

                pos.setXYZ( i, px, py, pz );
                pos.needsUpdate = true;

            }
        }
    }

    createText(){

        let thePoints = [];

        let shapes = this.font.generateShapes( this.data.text , this.data.textSize  );
        let geometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry( shapes );
        geometry.computeBoundingBox();

        const xMid = - 0.5 * ( geometry.boundingBox.max.x - geometry.boundingBox.min.x );
        const yMid =  (geometry.boundingBox.max.y - geometry.boundingBox.min.y)/2.85;

        geometry.center();

        let holeShapes = [];

        for ( let q = 0; q < shapes.length; q ++ ) {

            let shape = shapes[ q ];

            if ( shape.holes && shape.holes.length > 0 ) {

                for ( let  j = 0; j < shape.holes.length; j ++ ) {

                    let  hole = shape.holes[ j ];
                    holeShapes.push( hole );
                }
            }

        }
        shapes.push.apply( shapes, holeShapes );

        let colors = [];
        let sizes = [];

        for ( let  x = 0; x < shapes.length; x ++ ) {

            let shape = shapes[ x ];

            const amountPoints = ( shape.type == 'Path') ? this.data.amount/2 : this.data.amount;

            let points = shape.getSpacedPoints( amountPoints ) ;

            points.forEach( ( element, z ) => {

                const a = new THREE.Vector3( element.x, element.y, 0 );
                thePoints.push( a );
                colors.push( this.colorChange.r, this.colorChange.g, this.colorChange.b);
                sizes.push( 1 )

                });
        }

        let geoParticles = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints( thePoints );
        geoParticles.translate( xMid, yMid, 0 );

        geoParticles.setAttribute( 'customColor', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute( colors, 3 ) );
        geoParticles.setAttribute( 'size', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute( sizes, 1) );

        const material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
            uniforms: {
                color: { value: new THREE.Color( 0xffffff ) },
                pointTexture: { value: this.particleImg }
            },
            vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertexshader' ).textContent,
            fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentshader' ).textContent,

            blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
            depthTest: false,
            transparent: true,
        } );

        this.particles = new THREE.Points( geoParticles, material );
        this.scene.add( this.particles );

        this.geometryCopy = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
        this.geometryCopy.copy( this.particles.geometry );

    }

    visibleHeightAtZDepth ( depth, camera ) {

      const cameraOffset = camera.position.z;
      if ( depth < cameraOffset ) depth -= cameraOffset;
      else depth += cameraOffset;

      const vFOV = camera.fov * Math.PI / 180;

      return 2 * Math.tan( vFOV / 2 ) * Math.abs( depth );
    }

    visibleWidthAtZDepth( depth, camera ) {

      const height = this.visibleHeightAtZDepth( depth, camera );
      return height * camera.aspect;

    }

    distance (x1, y1, x2, y2){

        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x1 - x2), 2) + Math.pow((y1 - y2), 2));
    }
}
```

Comment: a few things that are unclear to me: when you say that you want to change the color of the particles what do you really want to do? changing the white into a different fixed color? changing the white into a different color only if the mouse hovers on them? anything else? I mean, what's the ideal behavior for the color of your particles? my understanding is that you want to get rid of the white color but not sure what you want them to look like PS is the background color now ok? it seems you eventually fixed it but the question still mentions this too

Comment: thnx for comment, yes background is fixed: "this.scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0x3c4a53 );"
the thing i want is to change white and yellow fixed colors of the text that's it

Comment: @ErfanQSN you can try to ask the author on the forum: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/interactive-text-with-particles/23366. But from what I see in the code, it uses `this.colorChange.setHSL(); coulors.setXYZ(); coulors.needsUpdate = true;` lines for the setting of color.

Comment: thnks for contact, yes the change color is setHSL but idont know how to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave a look to your code and your comments

- how to use `setHSL()`: quite easy

H values are between 0 and 360, S and L between 0 and 100. You can see this clearly [here](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_hsl.asp). The same link will shortcut the colors selection too

On the other side, ThreeJS defines this values on a different pattern, i.e. each of the H,S,L values is between 0.0 and 1.0

So if you wanna go green `[120,100,50]` you will translate the ThreeJS `setHSL()` call with values `[0.33,1,0.5]` where `0.33=120/360`

- changing the colors in your code

```
const preload = () => {

    let manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
    manager.onLoad = function() {
        const environment = new Environment(typo, particle);
    }

    var typo = null;
    const loader = new THREE.FontLoader(manager);
    const font = loader.load('https://res.cloudinary.com/dydre7amr/raw/upload/v1612950355/font_zsd4dr.json', function(font) {
        typo = font;
    });
    const particle = new THREE.TextureLoader(manager).load('https://res.cloudinary.com/dfvtkoboz/image/upload/v1605013866/particle_a64uzf.png');

}

if (document.readyState === "complete" || (document.readyState !== "loading" && !document.documentElement.doScroll))
    preload();
else
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", preload);

class Environment {

    constructor(font, particle) {

        this.font = font;
        this.particle = particle;
        this.container = document.querySelector('#magic');
        this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
        this.createCamera();
        this.createRenderer();
        this.setup()
        this.bindEvents();
    }

    bindEvents() {

        window.addEventListener('resize', this.onWindowResize.bind(this));

    }

    setup() {

        this.createParticles = new CreateParticles(this.scene, this.font, this.particle, this.camera, this.renderer);
    }

    render() {

        this.createParticles.render()
        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera)
    }

    createCamera() {

        this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(65, this.container.clientWidth / this.container.clientHeight, 1, 10000);
        this.camera.position.set(0, 0, 100);

    }

    createRenderer() {

        this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        this.renderer.setSize(this.container.clientWidth, this.container.clientHeight);

        this.renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2));

        this.renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
        this.container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);

        this.renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
            this.render()
        })

    }

    onWindowResize() {

        this.camera.aspect = this.container.clientWidth / this.container.clientHeight;
        this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        this.renderer.setSize(this.container.clientWidth, this.container.clientHeight);

    }
}

class CreateParticles {

    constructor(scene, font, particleImg, camera, renderer) {

        this.scene = scene;
        this.font = font;
        this.particleImg = particleImg;
        this.camera = camera;
        this.renderer = renderer;

        this.raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
        this.mouse = new THREE.Vector2(-200, 200);

        this.colorChange = new THREE.Color();

        this.buttom = false;

        this.data = {

            text: 'FUTURE\nIS NOW',
            amount: 1500,
            particleSize: 1,
            particleColor: 0xffffff,
            textSize: 16,
            area: 250,
            ease: .05,
        }

        this.setup();
        this.bindEvents();

    }


    setup() {

        const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(this.visibleWidthAtZDepth(100, this.camera), this.visibleHeightAtZDepth(100, this.camera));
        const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            color: 0x00ff00,
            transparent: true
        });
        this.planeArea = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        this.planeArea.visible = false;
        this.createText();

    }

    bindEvents() {

        document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.onMouseDown.bind(this));
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.onMouseMove.bind(this));
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', this.onMouseUp.bind(this));

    }

    onMouseDown() {

        this.mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
        this.mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

        const vector = new THREE.Vector3(this.mouse.x, this.mouse.y, 0.5);
        vector.unproject(this.camera);
        const dir = vector.sub(this.camera.position).normalize();
        const distance = -this.camera.position.z / dir.z;
        this.currenPosition = this.camera.position.clone().add(dir.multiplyScalar(distance));

        const pos = this.particles.geometry.attributes.position;
        this.buttom = true;
        this.data.ease = .01;

    }

    onMouseUp() {

        this.buttom = false;
        this.data.ease = .05;
    }

    onMouseMove() {

        this.mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
        this.mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

    }

    render(level) {

        const time = ((.001 * performance.now()) % 12) / 12;
        const zigzagTime = (1 + (Math.sin(time * 2 * Math.PI))) / 6;

        this.raycaster.setFromCamera(this.mouse, this.camera);

        const intersects = this.raycaster.intersectObject(this.planeArea);

        if (intersects.length > 0) {

            const pos = this.particles.geometry.attributes.position;
            const copy = this.geometryCopy.attributes.position;
            const coulors = this.particles.geometry.attributes.customColor;
            const size = this.particles.geometry.attributes.size;

            const mx = intersects[0].point.x;
            const my = intersects[0].point.y;
            const mz = intersects[0].point.z;

            for (var i = 0, l = pos.count; i < l; i++) {

                const initX = copy.getX(i);
                const initY = copy.getY(i);
                const initZ = copy.getZ(i);

                let px = pos.getX(i);
                let py = pos.getY(i);
                let pz = pos.getZ(i);

                // base color when the mouse is distant
                // color that will be distorted when the mouse hovers on the text
                // e.g. red
                this.colorChange.setHSL(0, 1, .50)
                coulors.setXYZ(i, this.colorChange.r, this.colorChange.g, this.colorChange.b)
                coulors.needsUpdate = true;

                size.array[i] = this.data.particleSize;
                size.needsUpdate = true;

                let dx = mx - px;
                let dy = my - py;
                const dz = mz - pz;

                const mouseDistance = this.distance(mx, my, px, py)
                let d = (dx = mx - px) * dx + (dy = my - py) * dy;
                const f = -this.data.area / d;

                if (this.buttom) {

                    const t = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
                    px -= f * Math.cos(t);
                    py -= f * Math.sin(t);

                    //onMouseDown color
                    //e.g. light blue when zigzagTime equals 0 but keep pressing on the text and the color will change because of the time dependency
                    this.colorChange.setHSL(.5 + zigzagTime, 1.0, .5)
                    coulors.setXYZ(i, this.colorChange.r, this.colorChange.g, this.colorChange.b)
                    coulors.needsUpdate = true;

                    if ((px > (initX + 70)) || (px < (initX - 70)) || (py > (initY + 70) || (py < (initY - 70)))) {
                        //color of the external particles when mouse is down on the text
                        //e.g. yellow
                        this.colorChange.setHSL(.15, 1.0, .5);
                        coulors.setXYZ(i, this.colorChange.r, this.colorChange.g, this.colorChange.b)
                        coulors.needsUpdate = true;

                    }

                } else {

                    if (mouseDistance < this.data.area) {

                        if (i % 5 == 0) {

                            const t = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
                            px -= .03 * Math.cos(t);
                            py -= .03 * Math.sin(t);

                            // changing the color around the mouse position
                            // e.g. green
                            this.colorChange.setHSL(.33, 1.0, .5)
                            coulors.setXYZ(i, this.colorChange.r, this.colorChange.g, this.colorChange.b)
                            coulors.needsUpdate = true;

                            size.array[i] = this.data.particleSize / 1.2;
                            size.needsUpdate = true;

                        } else {

                            const t = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
                            px += f * Math.cos(t);
                            py += f * Math.sin(t);

                            pos.setXYZ(i, px, py, pz);
                            pos.needsUpdate = true;

                            size.array[i] = this.data.particleSize * 1.3;
                            size.needsUpdate = true;
                        }

                        if ((px > (initX + 10)) || (px < (initX - 10)) || (py > (initY + 10) || (py < (initY - 10)))) {
                            // changing color of the external particles when mouse is down on the text
                            this.colorChange.setHSL(.15, 1.0, .5)
                            coulors.setXYZ(i, this.colorChange.r, this.colorChange.g, this.colorChange.b)
                            coulors.needsUpdate = true;

                            size.array[i] = this.data.particleSize / 1.8;
                            size.needsUpdate = true;

                        }
                    }

                }

                px += (initX - px) * this.data.ease;
                py += (initY - py) * this.data.ease;
                pz += (initZ - pz) * this.data.ease;

                pos.setXYZ(i, px, py, pz);
                pos.needsUpdate = true;

            }
        }
    }

    createText() {

        let thePoints = [];

        let shapes = this.font.generateShapes(this.data.text, this.data.textSize);
        let geometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(shapes);
        geometry.computeBoundingBox();

        const xMid = -0.5 * (geometry.boundingBox.max.x - geometry.boundingBox.min.x);
        const yMid = (geometry.boundingBox.max.y - geometry.boundingBox.min.y) / 2.85;

        geometry.center();

        let holeShapes = [];

        for (let q = 0; q < shapes.length; q++) {

            let shape = shapes[q];

            if (shape.holes && shape.holes.length > 0) {

                for (let j = 0; j < shape.holes.length; j++) {

                    let hole = shape.holes[j];
                    holeShapes.push(hole);
                }
            }

        }
        shapes.push.apply(shapes, holeShapes);

        let colors = [];
        let sizes = [];

        for (let x = 0; x < shapes.length; x++) {

            let shape = shapes[x];

            const amountPoints = (shape.type == 'Path') ? this.data.amount / 2 : this.data.amount;

            let points = shape.getSpacedPoints(amountPoints);

            points.forEach((element, z) => {

                const a = new THREE.Vector3(element.x, element.y, 0);
                thePoints.push(a);
                colors.push(this.colorChange.r, this.colorChange.g, this.colorChange.b);
                sizes.push(1)

            });
        }

        let geoParticles = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(thePoints);
        geoParticles.translate(xMid, yMid, 0);

        geoParticles.setAttribute('customColor', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(colors, 3));
        geoParticles.setAttribute('size', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(sizes, 1));

        const material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({

            uniforms: {
                color: {
                    value: new THREE.Color(0xffffff)
                },
                pointTexture: {
                    value: this.particleImg
                }
            },
            vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertexshader').textContent,
            fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragmentshader').textContent,

            blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
            depthTest: false,
            transparent: true,
        });

        this.particles = new THREE.Points(geoParticles, material);
        this.scene.add(this.particles);

        this.geometryCopy = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
        this.geometryCopy.copy(this.particles.geometry);

    }

    visibleHeightAtZDepth(depth, camera) {

        const cameraOffset = camera.position.z;
        if (depth < cameraOffset) depth -= cameraOffset;
        else depth += cameraOffset;

        const vFOV = camera.fov * Math.PI / 180;

        return 2 * Math.tan(vFOV / 2) * Math.abs(depth);
    }

    visibleWidthAtZDepth(depth, camera) {

        const height = this.visibleHeightAtZDepth(depth, camera);
        return height * camera.aspect;

    }

    distance(x1, y1, x2, y2) {

        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x1 - x2), 2) + Math.pow((y1 - y2), 2));
    }
}
```

This should solve your issue from a theoretical and practical point of view